# Polymer + jquery + slick carousel not work

Tags: jquery, polymer, slick.js

I've a conceptual problem between Polymer and jQuery selector, in particular with slick.js plugin.

this is a polymer-element definition

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../speech-element/speech-element.html">
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/slick/dist/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="./sequence-speech-questions.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="sequence-speech-questions" attributes="text_list">
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sequence-speech-questions.css">
    <div class="single-item">
        <template repeat="{{text in text_list}}">
          <speech-element text="{{text}}"></speech-element>
        </template>
   </div>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

and this is the **sequence-speech-questions.js**

```
Polymer("sequence-speech-questions", {
   // define element prototype here
ready: function () {
    this.text_list = JSON.parse(this.text_list);
},
domReady: function () {
  $('.single-item').slick();
}
});
```

Finally, the jquery selector not work

[image]

Some one have an idea how to fix this jquery error over polymer

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery does not exist within the context of a webcomponent or polymer in this case.

Maybe you should try to make their own modifications jquery from the main page, something like:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.single-item', function(){$(this).slick();});
```